# How to adjust width of line on horizontal charts with python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, linewidth

I have actually 2 questions.
I am trying to make a chart displaying both horizontal bar lines and vertical plot lines with `matplotlib`. This is a currency price chart. X ordinate is `date` but I use numbers for now. Y ordinate is `price`. And volume that has taken in the price gap is horizontal line. Code works when prices over 10 or something. But some currencies has very low prices. Like `0.000000123` In that case, the horizontal line width fills entire chart.
Here is the succesfull chart:

[image]
Short version of code is :

```
y_pos = list(gap_df.index)
plt.barh(y_pos, np.array(gap_df['Volume']))
plt.plot(np.array(data['Close']))
```

`gap_df` is a pandas dataframe, Volume is only column and index is prices;
y_pos is index of `gap_df`

```
len(gap_df) = 341
```

and

```
gap_df.sort_values(by='Volume',ascending = False).iloc[:10]
9150.0     160
9050.0     157
9100.0     157
6500.0     155
9250.0     152
...
```

So 9150 has to be longest horizontal line but there is no line on that price. I use pycharm and it creates chart on new window and when I zoom slightly in some lines gets disappeared and new ones shows up. Any help to solve this?

Second question is line width. I couldn't make line thinner. When price is very low like min is 0.0000004 it gets like this:

[image]

```
    plt.barh(y_pos, np.array(gap_df['Volume']), linewidth = 0.0000001)
```

I tried several linewidth floats and integers but it didn't change anything.
Any help to adjust width of horizontal line?

```
Env: python 3.7, matplotlib 3.1.0
```

Thanks.

Comment: maybe you want to adjust height since its a horizontal bar plot?

Comment: You are right!!! How couldn't I see that... It is better to shut everything off and take a look after a while. Thank you.

Comment: I've also made the same mistake.